# Synchronous useEffect requests

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have a useEffect which fetches data on page load and I am trying to add another fetch as soon as I receive a property from the initial call's JSON object. Is having 2 useEffects considered a good practice or shall I do it a different way?

```
const [account, setAccount] = useState({});
const [billing, setBilling] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchAccountData = async () => {
    const rawRes = await fetch(`/customers/${customerId}`);
    const res = await rawRes.json();
    setAccount(res);
  };
  fetchAccountData();
}, []);
```

I am trying to have a function which does one thing so I avoided adding 2nd useEffect's function to the first one. This is my approach

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchAccountData = async () => {
    const rawRes = await fetch(`/customers/${customerId}`);
    const res = await rawRes.json();
    setAccount(res);
  };
  fetchAccountData();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (accountData.endDate) {
    const fetchBillingData = async () => {
      const rawRes = await fetch(`/customers/${customerId}/billing`);
      const res = await rawRes.json();
      setBilling(res);
    };
  fetchBillingData();
}, [accountData.endDate]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, as your function is asynchronous and you're using await, writing it like this will achieve the result you want: `trying to add another fetch as soon as I receive a property from the initial call's JSON object`

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchAccountData = async () => {
    const rawRes = await fetch(`/customers/${customerId}`);
    const res = await rawRes.json();
    setAccount(res);

    const rawRes2 = await fetch(`/customers/${customerId}/billing`);
    const res2 = await rawRes.json();
    setBilling(res2);
  };
  fetchAccountData();
}, []);
```